# How do I add different delays?

Tags: python

So I have this and I want ;fish and ;hunt to run every 5 minutes and ;sell every 2 minutes but I do not know how to do that.

```
import pyautogui
import time

running = True
while True:
    pyautogui.typewrite(";fish")
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    pyautogui.typewrite(";hunt")
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    pyautogui.typewrite(";sell")
    pyautogui.press('enter')
 
    time.sleep(5 * 60)
```

Comment: have you tried threads?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can solve your problem by using Threading, which will run paralel process of you funcitons at the same time and with a timer if you want, like this:

```
import time
import threading
import pyautogui

def wait(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)

def fish_hunt():
    running = True
    while running == True:
        pyautogui.typewrite(";fish")
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.typewrite(";hunt")
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        wait(5*60)
    
def sell():
    running = True
    while running == True:
        pyautogui.typewrite(";sell")
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        wait(2*60)
    
threading.Thread(target=fish_hunt).start()
threading.Thread(target=sell).start()
```

Also a good reminder is that this will not stop! It's a infinite loop, so if you want to stop you should add an condition to the loop that will make it stop!